# Hacer scroll automático al llegar a cierto lugar de la página

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Al cargar la página automaticamente inicio un `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#lugarABajar').offset().top }, 10000);` de `jquery` para que comience el scroll hacia abajo de la página hasta el lugar donde se encuentra el elemento  con el `id="lugarABajar"`, pero requiero que al momento de llegar hasta ese punto se aplique automaticamente el ascenso hasta el inicio de la página `$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);`. ¿Hay alguna manera de disparar la animación de ascenso en cuanto se llegue a ese punto, sin esperar a que pase el tiempo indicado en el descenso?

Answer (score 1):

La misma funcion `animate()` tiene un **callback** que se ejecuta después de que haya terminado la acción, de esta manera, espero te sirva.

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#lugarABajar').offset().top }, 10000,function(){

$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: Hola Vick Muñoz, lo que pasa al usar este método es que termina de hacer el scroll hasta el punto que le indico, pero lo hace más rápido a los 10 segundos que le indico, pero aunque realice el scroll y lo termine antes digamos 5 segundos, vuelve a subir hasta que pasen 10 segundos, lo que busco es que al llegar al punto indicado suba de nuevo sin tener que esperar esos extras 5 segundos, a lo mucho 1 segundo.

Comment: @M.Gar Lo que sucede es que si le pones un delay de 10 segundos es lo que se va a tardar en ejecutar la función `animate()` más no así el tiempo en que tarde el scroll al llegar al final, necesitarías una pagina con un **height** demasiado basto para que cubra esos 10 segundos en lo que tarda en llegar el scroll hasta abajo, por eso si tu página no tiene lo suficiente vas a ver que llega en 3, 4 o 5 segundos y no es que tarde en otros 5 segundos en subir, si no que aún no completa los 10 segundos que le pasas por delay.